# How do I perform double substitiution of shell variables?

Tags: sh, posix

I have the following script stored in test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

key1=foo
key2=bar
key3=baz

for i in 1 2 3; do
    echo $i
    echo ${key${i}}
done
```

When I run it I get the output

```
1
test.sh: 9: Bad substitution
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#!/bin/sh

key1=foo
key2=bar
key3=baz

for i in 1 2 3; do
  echo $i
  eval echo \$"key$i"
done
```

Output:

```
1
foo
2
bar
3
baz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
eval echo '$'key$i
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/917313/10693596

Short answer is this is not possible in `bash`.

Update: depending on what you are ultimately after, using indirect expansion might work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42066820/10693596